# Galaxy tab charging dock stops charging when USB device is attached

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-tab, docking-station

I recently bought this charging dock by Brodit for my Samsung Galaxy Active 2 (v. 3.9.0) with Android 9: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00UASMT2Y/. I was hoping to constantly keep the tablet running at a fixed place.

If I put the tablet in the Charging dock, it starts charging as it should. If I now connect an OTG USB device (namely a SkyController 2 for a Parrot Drone), the dock seemingly stops charging. A measurement of the current between dock and tablet seems to confirm that.
The charging symbol in the tablet still stays on since the SkyController delivers the usual 0.5A. Of course, this is not enough to compensate for the energy lost, so the tablet's charge slowly decreases.

Is it really usual behaviour that connecting a USB device disables charging through the dock and, if yes, is there a switch in Android to change this?

If this is really not possible, is there another solution to keep the tablet charged while using a USB device at the same time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In USB OTG mode the phone/tablet does not only stop charging, OTG is designed to deliver power from the phone/tablet to the attached OTG device. At least with micro USB I think it was standardized this way. But some devices may work differently. Charging and using an USB port at the same time was first standardized as far as I know in USB-C with power delivery.